# Pass 'div' element as parameter to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild, createelement

I need to create, decorate and append child 'divs' to existing. For example, after the appendChildren is executed, following divs

```
    <div id="a">
      <div id="b">
      </div>
    </div>
```

should take the following form (assuming decorateDiv adds text "This is new div" inside new div)

```
    <div id="a">
      <div id="b">
        <div>"This is new div"</div>
      </div>
      <div>"This is new div"</div>
    </div>
```

Here is my code

```
    function appendChildren() {
    var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    decorateDiv(newDiv);
    allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
    }
    }


    function decorateDiv(div) {
      var x = document.getElementByTagName("div");
      var t = document.createTextNode("This is new div");  
    x.appendChild(t); 
    }
```

I am completely new to JavaSpript. What am I doing wrong? Please help me to fix bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the parameter `div` and the `decorateDiv` should look like this:

```
function decorateDiv(div) {
   //div is the object element
   var t = document.createTextNode("This is new div");  
   div.appendChild(t); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. but http://jsbin.com/sebazafoqu/1/edit?html,js,console,output - It's still not working

Comment: It's working < http://jsbin.com/lilesaruto/2/edit > but it's creating an infinite loop as you can see.

Comment: sorry, but how I can fix the infinite loop problem then?

Comment: < http://jsbin.com/lilesaruto/3/edit > By adding `var initialDivNum = allDivs.length;` before the loop will get the initial length of the number of divs

Answer (score 0):

The parameter 'div' that you are passing to function 'decorateDiv' has nowhere been used.
You can change your decorateDiv function like as below:

```
function decorateDiv(div) {  
var t = document.createTextNode("This is new div");   
div.appendChild(t);   
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

"allDivs" variable get update when to appendChild to any div because to stores array of elements of "div" TagName.
So, use class for fetching divs.

```
<div id="a" class="test">
A  
<div id="b" class="test">
    B  
</div>
</div>
```

Here is user script:

```
function appendChildren() {
        var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
            for (var i = 0 ; i < allDivs.length ; i++) {
                var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                decorateDiv(newDiv);
                allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
            }
        }
        function decorateDiv(div) {
          var t = document.createTextNode("This is new div");  
            div.appendChild(t); 
        }
        appendChildren();
```

And  also you are not using parameter passed to decorative function.

This will work. Try this..